# MYSQL: Count # of rows in another table corresponding to rows in first table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three tables: Accounts (a list of businesses, each with an AccountID), Contacts (a list of people, tied back to the Accounts table by AccountID), and ContactComments (a list of comments left for various contacts, tied back to the Contacts table by ContactID).  I am trying to display a list of all the contacts, as well as how many comments each contact has gotten (some have zero comments).  This is my current query:

```
    select
    a.ContactID, a.ContactType, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Phone, a.Email,
    b.AccountName, 
    c.ContactID, count(c.CommentID) as CountCon
    from
    Contacts a, Accounts b, ContactComments c 
    where 
    a.AccountID = b.AccountID 
    group by a.ContactID 
    order by a.LastName
```

When I display this on my page via PHP, I'm getting this:

```
Nonexistant Holdings, LLC   Larry Boe   941-555-8888    larry@example.com   View Comments   16

Another Subcontractor, Inc. Eric Coe    941-555-6000    eric@example.com    View Comments   16

Nonexistant Holdings, LLC   Yasmeen Crith   941-555-9999    yasmeen@asdf.com    View Comments   16

ABC Realty, Inc.    Jane Doe    941-555-1111    jane@example.com    View Comments   16

XYZ Properties, LLC Jim Foe 941-555-2222    jim@example.com View Comments   16
```

16, at the end of each line, is currently the total number of comments in the Comments table.  I realize that my query is off because my count(c.CommentID) is, of course, counting all the comments.  How can I adjust this so that I get the number of comments *per contact* and display that at the end of each line (including zero if the contact has no comments)?  Is this something I would need a join to accomplish?  (Not too familiar with joins, yet.)

Comment: You are just joining `ContactComments c` to all rows. You need to specify how it relates to `Contacts a` ie. -> `WHERE a.AccountID = b.AccountID **AND a.ContactID = c.ContactID**`

Comment: Couldn't have said it much better than Sean.

Comment: But then it only returns a list of contacts that have comments.  I wanted to return a list of ALL contacts, even the ones with zero comments, and have it show 0 at the end of the line.

Comment: You could use a `CASE` in your select - change `count(c.CommentID) as CountCon` to `CASE WHEN count(c.CommentID) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE count(c.CommentID) END as CountCon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly declaring your joins will help you see where you have problems. For example this is roughly what your query would translate to if you explicitly declared your joins

```
select
a.ContactID, a.ContactType, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Phone, a.Email,
b.AccountName, 
c.ContactID, count(c.CommentID) as CountCon
from
Contacts a
join Accounts b on a.AccountID = b.AccountID
join ContactComments c --(but you are missing join qualifiers so this would need to be declared as a cross join for your query to run)
group by a.ContactID 
order by a.LastName
```

what you want is this (EDITED: updated isnull to ifnull as per commentors):

```
select
a.ContactID, a.ContactType, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Phone, a.Email,
b.AccountName, 
c.ContactID, ifnull(count(c.CommentID), 0) as CountCon
from
Contacts a
join Accounts b on a.AccountID = b.AccountID
left join ContactComments c on a.ContactID = c.ContactID
group by a.ContactID 
order by a.LastName
```

Comment: I had to change "isnull" to "ifnull" 
(isnull was throwing an error) but otherwise this worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @rhealitycheck you want [`ifnull()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)->`If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.` INSTEAD of [`isnull()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)->`If expr is NULL, ISNULL() returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.`

Comment: @PhillipsContracting updated to be ifnull, i typically use sql server and isnull apparently behaves differently in mysql.